# How to save Object with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have 3 class, and i use DAOHelper.
But my friend said : "Problem with Object in DAOHelper"
Can you explain for me ? tks all.
Can you suggest me other way ?

1.EMPLOYEE

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long Id;

@Column(name="EMPNAME")
private String empName;

@Column(name="PHONE")
private String phone;
protected Employee(){}
// get and set method()
}
```

2.DEPARTMENT

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long Id;

@Column(name="DEPNAME")
private String depName;

@Column(name="ADDRESS")
private String Address;
protected Department(){}
// get and set method()
}
```

3.CUSTOMER

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private long Id;

@Column(name="CUSNAME")
private String cusName;

@Column(name="ADDRESS")
private String Address;
protected Customer(){}
// get and set method()
}
```

I use DAOHelper class.

```
public class DAOHelper{
public Long save(Object obj) {
    Long idInput = null;
    try {
        startOperation();
        idInput = (Long) session.save(obj);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return idInput;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: _my friend said : "Problem with Object in DAOHelper"_ Unless the friend is your compiler, I don't think you should really concern yourself with such statements.

Comment: i think Allocating large blocks of memory with new Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API method [Session.save(Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) takes input as an Object, so there is no problem if you try to call `session.save(obj)` in your `DAOHelper` class, so no problem with Object in DAOHelper.

But:

```
idInput = (Long) session.save(obj);
```

You are casting the return type to `Long` so you will face exceptions if the identifier type of the entity object is not of type `Long`.

As per your code it seems you are declaring the `session` variable as an instance variable. As `session` is not thread-safe you will face issues in multi-threading environment.